# Windows Explorer View changes rapidly

Tags: windows-7

Windows Explorer on an up to date Windows 7 desktop is experiencing frequent but inconsistent bursts of instability when the View (i.e. Icons, Tiles, Details) rapidly rotate so fast that you cannot click on file quick enough to open it. Navigation Panel and Menus are also unstable. As quickly as the problem starts it can stop and everything is normal. Other applications do not show similar problems.

Comment: Did you enable to show explorer ribbon?

Comment: By "rotate" I mean that it changes to Icon then to Tiles then to Details very fast and it just keeps going round the different views. The Explorer ribbon is showing.